# How can I get the logging directory of a RollingFileAppender from log4cxx?

Tags: c++, log4cxx

I'm using XML to configure log4cxx. The appender is a `RollingFileAppender` that outputs to a folder like `yyyy/MM/dd/HHmm`, and I need to know what that folder is at the end of the program.

I can't get the current `yyyy/MM/dd/HHmm` at runtime because that value will likely be different than it was when the log directory was created. After scanning log4cxx's documentation, I found only one function that was relevant:

```
log4cxx::FileAppender::getFile()
```

which returns the file that an appender is logging to.


The problem with that is that calls to `log4cxx::Logger::getAppender()` yield only `AppenderPtr`s- I could `dynamic_cast` this into a `FileAppender` if I know that's the ultimate type, but this introduces uncertainty into the program. Is there really no way to get the current log directory from log4cxx?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no(easy) way to get the name of the file that the RollingFileAppender is using.

Using `Logger::getAppender()` is the best way to get the correct appender that you are looking for.  Since the appenders should all have unique names, there shouldn't be any issue with casting to the correct type.  If you want to be safe about casting, use `log4cxx::cast<FileAppender>( AppenderPtr )` which will return an invalid pointer if the object is unable to be casted to the correct type.